# Element is not visible in appium inspector for IOS app

Tags: appium

I am using Appium v1.0.2-beta.1, I have one element displayed on screen but not able to locate it using appium inspector

I have also fetched the source of the app, but could not find that particular element. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: can you post the screenshot of appium inspector ?, so that i can help you

Comment: I am afraid I can't. since that is an internal application

Comment: without the see the nature of the element, i can't help sorry bro.